# How to remove part from string strat from point or word?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I want to remove part of string from special world using php lang for example :

```
$string1 = "xABCb1/DEF/GHI/GKL";
$string2 = "yABCz/DEF/MNO/PQR";
$string3 = "zABC1112/DEF/STU/VWX";
```

I want to remove all words before from (DEF) and the result looks like this

```
$string1 = "DEF/GHI/GKL";
$string2 = "DEF/MNO/PQR";
$string3 = "DEF/STU/VWX";
```

The words before (DEF) are not static . it is changing. I just want the function to clear all the words that before (DEF)

Comment: OK, great plan. So what have you tried, where is your code? You see, we are not a free coding service, we are here to help you to fix your own code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want here e.g string replace functions, regex and so on. But this is my way using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) because always try to use built in method instead of using regex at **first**.

```
$string1 = "xABCb1/DEF/GHI/GKL";
$string2 = "yABCz/DEF/MNO/PQR";
$string3 = "zABC1112/DEF/STU/VWX";
echo  strstr($string1, 'DEF')."\n"; 
echo  strstr($string2, 'DEF')."\n";
echo  strstr($string3, 'DEF');
```

**Output:**

```
DEF/GHI/GKL
DEF/MNO/PQR
DEF/STU/VWX
```

See Demo: https://eval.in/969773

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions offer a very powerful tool for such primitive string manipulations:

```
<?php
$input = [
    "xABCb1/DEF/GHI/GKL",
    "yABCz/DEF/MNO/PQR",
    "zABC1112/DEF/STU/VWX"
];
$anchor = "DEF";
$output = preg_replace('|^.*/(DEF/)|', '$1', $input);
print_r($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DEF/GHI/GKL
    [1] => DEF/MNO/PQR
    [2] => DEF/STU/VWX
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $string1 = "xABCb1/DEF/GHI/GKL";
    $string2 = "yABCz/DEF/MNO/PQR";
    $string3 = "zABC1112/DEF/STU/VWX";

    $string1 = ltrim($string1, 'xABCb1/');
    var_dump($string1); 

    $string2 = ltrim($string2, 'yABCz/');
    var_dump($string2);

    $string3 = ltrim($string3, 'zABC1112/');
    var_dump($string3);
```

**Output**

```
 DEF/GHI/GKL
 DEF/MNO/PQR
 DEF/STU/VWX
```